# PANTALLA NEGRA ANDROID AVD MANAGER

Tags: android, android-studio

buenas tardes.
Estoy empezando en android, desde cero. instalé android studio y al tratar de ejecutar el AVD manager y crear un dispositivo virtual me topé con el problema que mi computadora al tener AMD y no INTEL, tenía que bajar otra imagen que de la sección de "Other Images", entendí que cualquiera que fuera arm. bajé 2 pero al ejecutar ambas, el emulador simplemente se queda en pantalla negra.

también intenté en bajar la cantidad de ram que se le asigna al dispositivo porque leí que en algunos casos podría traer problemas pero sigue sin funcionar.
Prácticamente toda la configuración está por default, no he movido nada más que instalar las imágenes.

Comment: Hola podrias subir la configuracion del emulador, ademas podrias fijarte en el Logcat, seguro encuentras algun error :D

Comment: En una oportunidad tambien tuve problemas para virtualizar utilizando AVD. Mi solución fue utilizar Genymotion, mas abajo de paso el URL > https://www.genymotion.com/desktop/ Basicamente es un gestor de dispositivos virtuales, en el puedes descargar diferentes dispositivos y modificar sus caracteristicas. Suerte, espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: En ocasiones tarda algunos minutos en inicializar el emulador, has revisado si se muestra algún mensaje de error en la consola?